# Set a faded darker background to a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, ios9

I'm trying to set a faded darker background to a navigation bar, as you can see on the image below.

[image]

I've tried with this code but it's not exactly what I expect.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)
```

I've found this topic, but without suitable answer:

[Shows a faded gray color view through iOS 7 Navigation bar of a UISplitViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512598/shows-a-faded-gray-color-view-through-ios-7-navigation-bar-of-a-uisplitviewcontr)

Any idea will be appreciated.

EDIT 6 oct 2015 : If somebody needs to know how to perform that

For Swift users :
- in particular viewcontroller : i use :

```
 self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "fadedimage.png"), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

in the main NavigationController (to apply that to the all navigationBar) i use :

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "fadedimage.png"), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: don't you the screenshot of the map on my post ?

Comment: I have an easy way to do this,let me post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the correct way, but you can achieve the same by using a custom image.

Donwload a transparent image from internet, I named it as transparent.png

and set the navigation bar background image:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transaprent.png" ] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f]];
```

This gives the result:
[image]

Later you can apply the shadow effect for the navigation bar.

Edit:

I donwloaded a custom shadow transparent png image, and applied it using above code.

[image]

You can still improve this with a better custom image as per your requirements.

Here is the image I used:

[image]

To remove the bottom border that appears on navbar, use this code:

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: thanks Mr.T, i put the code in Swift in my main post.

Comment: in the top where we can see the battery, the carrier, the time, it's still normal. the background image is not applied. Have you an idea why ?

Comment: do you mean the font for the battery and carrier should changee with the background image ?

Comment: On your example battery and carrier have the good black background as expected. In mine , i see the map on the background.