# How to implement this kind of blur effect iOS 8 & iOS 9?

Tags: objective-c, blur, ios9.1, xcode7.1, uiblureffect

[image]

As you can see ,the map view should display with blur effect. I tried the UIBlurEffect, stackoverflow suggestions  and many blur effect libraries but I not able achieve the actual effect.How can I achieve the exact blur effect , can anybody help me to fix it out ? Thanks,

Edit:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blurImage" ] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f]];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

While I implement the above code it looks like the below image,[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do u need blur on map or on navigation bar ?

Comment: show us what you tried, and how is it different than what you want to achieve?

Comment: did u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955102/set-a-faded-darker-background-to-a-uinavigationbar/32956423#32956423 ?

Comment: Yes, but without background image is there any possibility ?

Comment: that is the simplest way to do, I am not sure if there is a way add a gradient to a UIBlueEffect.

Comment: as far as i know, blur effect is unique, and we cant customise it!!! I mean in the sense change its opacity!!!

Comment: you can use  UIVisualEffectView for that and then play with the size of the view which you are adding as subview. you can use vibrancy or not in the subview depending to what you want to achieve. let me know if you need any sample codes. here is the link to the apple doc's https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html

Comment: @Mr.T I added the navigationbar background image to achieve the transparent but It always looks as white background.

Comment: what kind of image did u add ? does that image have transparency and is of type png ?