# Why do I have an excessive amount of space in a UITableView section header?

Tags: ipad, ios7, xcode5

I have used a `UITableView` control to show a list of customers that the user can select from. I've divided this into a number of sections, because the customers they need to select will vary from day to day — so the sections are used to divide between the days.

For some reason, there's an excessive amount of whitespace being included in the section header. I don't recall this being the case with iOS 5 (which this application was originally developed with).

[image]

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

FWIW, I'm not suppling a `heightForHeaderInSection:` method, so it's not that trivial. In the `titleForHeaderInSection:` method I'm returning a simple `NSString*` which represents the date.

Comment: Is it a Grouped Style? If yes, iOS7 change its behavior.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388429/uitableview-is-starting-with-an-offset-in-ios7
Solution I used: `[myTableView setTableHeaderView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [myTableView frame].size.width, 0.01f)]]; [self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];`

Comment: Is this inside a container view (embedded controller)? Cause it looks like an empty navigation bar on top of your header view, so you might have embedded a navigation controller instead of just a tableview.

Comment: No, it's a `UITableView`. It appears that with iOS 7 they want the table view to occupy the entire parent view so that you can scroll under the status bar. I don't want that though, because I need to display a summary of data above my table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [link to question 18388429](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388429/uitableview-is-starting-with-an-offset-in-ios7) provided by @Larme, and read through the suggestions there.

The simple fix for me was to turn off 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' for the view. That gave me the result I was after.