# ios Weird margin on view

Tags: ios, view, viewcontroller

i create a TabController inside a TabController with SegmentControl but i got that strange margin that came on the first page but when i click on other everything is fine why ?

I posted my first page and my second page :

[image: page 1]
[image: page 1]
**That how i implement my view when i click** :

```
- (void)setSelectedIndex:(NSInteger) position
{
    UIViewController* selectedController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:position];

    if (self.lastPositionOfPage == -1)
        self.lastPositionOfPage =  0;
    else
    {
        [selectedController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [selectedController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [selectedController removeFromParentViewController];

    }
    [selectedController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:selectedController];
    [self.content addSubview:selectedController.view];
    [selectedController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.lastPositionOfPage = position;


}
```

Comment: Do you have a `UITableView`?

Comment: Yes i have, just above the button blue button.I set his height to 0 when is empty.

Comment: Is it grouped? If yes, that normal. The iOS7 with grouped cell, "center vertically it) in iOS7. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799414/why-do-i-have-an-excessive-amount-of-space-in-a-uitableview-section-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks again to @Larme**. For people get same problem. Select your **UIViewController** in the **StoryBoard** then **unchecked** in **Exented Edges** all checkbox

[image]