# Why does my plain UITableView section footer float above my input's accessory view in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uistoryboard, inputview

I'm using storyboards to create a static UITableView with one section that has a header and a footer. Each tableview cell has a UITextField whose inputView is set to a UIPicker and the accessory view is a UIToolbar.

[image: How it should look]

This works great except the section footer floats way above the accessory view's toolbar like this in the sim:

[image: How it actually looks]

This only occurs in iOS 7 not 6. Any ideas?

Comment: Also I'm using BSKeyboardControls to help with pref, next buttons. https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls

Comment: It doesn't look related to BSKeyboardControls as I can reproduce it w/o BSKeyboardControls. Looks like it's just related to putting a textfield in a tableviewcell in a PLAIN style tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like UINavigationController's toolbar was to blame. Luckily for me I accidentally had it enabled. After removing it the problem was fixed. But if you need the bottom toolbar I don't know what the solution is.

Comment: I have same problem =/

Answer (score 0):

I have that same problem. My tableview was inside a View that had tabBar and a NavBar.

After some research, I found out that iOS7+ automatically adds a offset to the tableview when it is in a view with tabbar/navbar.

You can disable that automatically offset both via code or via Interface Builder.

Via Interface Builder, just uncheck the "Under Top Bars" (if you are using navbar) and "Under Bottom Bars" (if you are using tabbar) on the "Extended Edges" submenu on the View that has your tableview.

[image]

That should solve your problem.

For other answers on how to do it (and for the original @xudre's answer from whom I learned the solution - please vote his answer up) go to: [UITableView is starting with an offset in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388429/uitableview-is-starting-with-an-offset-in-ios-7)

Comment: I still want it to draw under the bars though for the blur effect.