# UITableView section header missplaced

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm getting really strange error in my UITableView. I'm using standard views and sections.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0f;
}

- (NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch (section)
{
    case kSectionProfile:
        return @"Profile";
        break;

    case kSectionContacts:
        return @"Contacts";
        break;

    case kSectionApps:
        return @"Apps";
        break;

    case kSectionSettings:
        return @"Settings";
        break;

    case kSectionCount:
        return nil;
        break;
}

return nil;
}
```

TableView comes from XIB.

[image]

Simulator:
[image]

[image]

This is top of UITableView, section is never touching top of visible area and cells are drawn about section header.
I have no idea what can be causing this strange problems. It seems that top of UITableView is not correctly calculated.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Untick the following boxes in the storyboard/XIB on the VC object in the hierarchy. [image]

From here: [UITableView is starting with an offset in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388429/uitableview-is-starting-with-an-offset-in-ios-7)

**Old answer:**

Use `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` delegate method and see if it helps.

E.g.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20.0f;
}
```

Comment: Already tried that - doesn't fix anything - just making headers bigger, but still they are not touching top of table