# Grouped UITableView 35 point / pixel top inset / padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Please note, I'm going to refer to points as pixels in this question.

I have a grouped `UITableView` with 3 sections, each with a 40 pixel tall header view. The first header in the table view seems to be given a y position of 35 pixels by the system.

I've tried messing around with `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` and a few other iOS 7 automatic pieces, but to no avail.

Why is my `UITableView` content being inset by 35 pixels?

EDIT: I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18938763/1292230) and many other threads on this. I have valid headers and header heights. Also, setting the default to `FLT_MIN`, 0.01f, 1.0f or 100.0f doesn't fix the problem.

Here is my header implementation:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *header = (self.headerViews.count > section ? self.headerViews[section] : nil);
    return (header.viewHeight ? : FLT_MIN);
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *header = (self.headerViews.count > section ? self.headerViews[section] : nil);
    return (header.viewHeight ? header : nil);
}
```

I'm also setting:

```
- (BOOL)automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets{return NO;}
```

and

```
[self setSectionHeaderHeight:FLT_MIN];
```

Comment: why are you referring to points as pixels? just say "points" if you mean "points". there is a reason for this distinction.

Comment: Have you looked into this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18938763/2150138)?

Comment: @Michael Because pixels are more widely understood and searched for.

Comment: hmm, someone who doesn't understand the difference shouldn't try to answer the question anyhow, IMHO

Comment: @Callistino Yes, I have. The biggest difference between that answer/question and mine is that I have headers with a height, so `0.0f` isn't even a factor. Also, I've tried setting it for the sake of testing.

Comment: Have you also used heightForHeaderInSection to set your appropriate header height?

Comment: @JordanClifton Yes, I have.

Comment: There are many answers to that question. I remember having the same problem in the past and only one of them worked. So make sure to try all of [them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst/18938763#18938763). Also, are you using a `UITableViewController` or a `UITableView` inside a `VC`?

Comment: @Callistino It's a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`

Comment: The "only way" I know of to get a **35 points y offset** in that combination, is if you are also **embedded** on a `NavigationController` and you `VC`'s top constraint is set to the bottom of the `NavC`.

Comment: @Callistino "top constraint"? I feel like you're on to something, as this is only affecting **some** of my tables.

Comment: You must have a **top constraint** on your `TV` to your `VC's main view`. That is the one I am referring to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52706/discussion-between-rileye-and-callistino)

Answer (score 8):

It seems that this:

```
[self setTableHeaderView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, FLT_MIN)]];
```

In init, where `self` is a `UITableView`, will get rid of the top 35 points.

Comment: I can see how this is working and none of the other did. Again, your case is specific to a `UITableView` inside a `VC` so all the other solutions involving `contentInset` or `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` would not work since they would be targeting the `VC` when the issue was inside the `UITableViewController` itself.

Comment: This is gold. Not that there's a difference between a table's section header view, which this isn't. This is a **table header**. For some reason just one of my tables had this set to a non zero value after a lot of fiddling in Interface Builder, I am guessing some IB bug. I wish I had seen this earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yep，i get this problem when i set tableview.tableFooterView and custom set section header height, then first section height has over 35 points.

Then i add a

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude))
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of getting the same issue you are getting and therefore, multiple solutions. I will try to list the ones I know with their corresponding solutions. Most of them are copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880341/why-is-there-extra-padding-at-the-top-of-my-uitableview-with-style-uitableviewst/18938763#18938763).

#### UITableView inside a UIViewController

This is a common one that trips people off because they think the problem is related to their `UITableView` and most of the time is actually the parent `UIViewController`.

If your `VC` is **embedded** on a `NavigationController`. You will get a 35 points **y offset** as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388821/2150138).

**Solutions**

- In Xcode Version > 5 on `VC` untick **Extended Edges "Under Top Bars** under the **Attributes Inspector** to remove the top `UITableView` content inset.
- **Constraints:** Your `VC` has a main **view** where all the other **subviews** are laid including your `UITableView`. You need to make sure that all **constraints** from your `UITableView` are **explicitily** set and **satisfied/non-ambiguous**.
- Set `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;`
- Set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`. This one can also be set on the storyboard by unchecking the **Adjust Scroll View Insets** checkbox for the view controller layout.
- Set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

---

#### General UITableView/UITableViewController

- Set the `tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`
- Set the `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-35, 0, 0, 0);` Pay attention to the **-35**. The negative number **offsets** the view.
- Declare this method (Can also be used for FooterSection):

```js
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

Comment: I need to set the height of my headers to `40.0f` and I don't have a need for an inset of `-20`, either. Also, I'm not using XIBs or auto-layout. As for the rest, that's already all set, but I still have a `35.0f` point inset. However, this is a good amalgamation of all of the information from other answers.

Comment: Yes, I didn't update the `-20` offset when copying here.