# Embed TableView In ContainerView is scrolled down at start

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, storyboard, uicontainerview

I made a static table view to be embed in a container view, the problem is 
that when the application start in the parent view controller the table view is scrolled down trunking the last item.I would like to see the first 3 items.

Here what i did try in the parent AND in the child view controller without any sucess :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        //Juste une section pour cette table static
        int rowCount = TableView.NumberOfRowsInSection(0);
        NSIndexPath path = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(rowCount - 1,0);
        TableView.ScrollToRow(path, UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, false);
        //TableView.ScrollEnabled = false;

    }
```

Here is an image of my problem :

[image: Resume]
Thanks!!

Comment: Check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388429/uitableview-is-starting-with-an-offset-in-ios-7

Comment: Did remove the extend edge TOP, BOTTOM and the Scrollview inset in my table view controller without success

Comment: Thanks ive found the solution with your URL

Answer (score 0):

1. Uncheck Adjust scroll View Inset on the embed view controller
2. Use this code in the embed view controller :

   ```
       public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
   {
       base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

       if (int.Parse(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion.Split('.')[0]) >= 7)
       {
           RectangleF navFrame = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame;
           float blankTopSpace = navFrame.Location.Y + navFrame.Size.Height;
           TableView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(-blankTopSpace, 0, 0, 0);
       }

   }
   ```