# White space at top of tableView embedded in a container view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uicontainerview

I have a `viewController` that has x 2 container views in it that hold x 2 different `tableViews`. I use a `segmentControl` at the top of the main view to switch between these two tableViews. It works just fine.

On one of the tableViews I want to drill down to show yet another tableView. Problem is, when I do it leaves a blank white space at the top of the view where the segment used to be (at least I think that is what is causing the white space.)

How do I ensure the `tableView` sits snuggly under the navigation bar?

Here are some images for reference:
1. Is the main view containing a segment control.
2. Is the container view.
[image]

Selecting a segment brings up a view like the one below. Which is fine.

[image]

But when I drill down I get this:

[image]

I can scroll up, no problem, and manually place the image under the nav bar, so this tells me its not that the view is not big enough.

How do I remove that white space above the image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of swift or xCode are you using? Have you used size classes or stack view. Did you used constraints for the layout? Can you share the code on github or dropbox so that we can have a look at it?

Comment: @Jeetendra Choudhary Swift 2.2; Xcode 7.3.1; No, not using size classes, no, not using stack view; yes I used constraints for the layout IN the cells, all done in StoryBoard. So I haven't got any relevant (view orientated) code to show you.

Comment: In your event details VC try writing     self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; this may help :)

Comment: set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to false or select view contrller -> uncheck scroll view insects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView is starting with an offset in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388429/uitableview-is-starting-with-an-offset-in-ios-7)

Comment: @sanman in viewDidLoad I assume?

Comment: @thecloud_of_unknowing yes in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `EventDetailVC` add these line in `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

If it not solve set `translucent` property of `navigationBar` to `true`

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Comment: Welcome... Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution can be this as well. Uncheck the **Adjust Scroll View Insets** and your problem will be solved.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Manjul. Nice easy approach.