# Strange top spacing for ScrollView

Tags: ios, autolayout, scrollview

[image]

[image]

I settled the scrollview and the image should be at the top.
But when I pushed this view on navigation controller it adds some strange spacing at the top

```
            if let destination = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(StoryboardNames.ItemDetailsView.rawValue) as? ItemDetailsViewConroller {
                destination.itemEntity = updatedItem
                self.navigationVC?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
            }
```

But, I'm opening this view from different navigation controllers.
From first the sizing is correct (no spacing at the top), but from another I receive this strange bug.
Does anyone know why this is caused?

Comment: Can you show the simulator screenshot? Also from storyboard select the ViewController having scrollView and from attribute inspector deselect the Adjust Scroll View Insets property.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38365491/6433023

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White space at top of tableView embedded in a container view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365355/white-space-at-top-of-tableview-embedded-in-a-container-view)

Comment: This quest has been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965485/why-does-xcode-add-space-for-a-top-bar

Comment: This question has already been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965485/why-does-xcode-add-space-for-a-top-bar

Answer (score 1):

write this below line in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Scrollview insets in storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This thing will be happening if and only if you are adding ScrollView or its subclass(tableview,collectionView,textview etc) at first position in viewController's main view. You can move it to second or any other position or solve by doing following thing:

select your viewcontroller, and see its layout attribute as shown in following image, here uncheck the "Adjust Scroll View Insets". This will stop adding 20 pixel space above.

[image]