# UITableView scroll jumps

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, contentoffset

Recently my app started doing scroll jumps when new ViewController was pushed like so:

[image: UITableViewController scroll jumps]

I have tried different answers but nothing seems to work. I have learned that my app was setting negative offset to `CGPointZero` after I have set:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

}

I have tried to find what was setting the offset and I have learnt that setContentOffset it was invoked from:

```
UIScrollViewInternal _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers that I found about this topics where suggesting to set:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

It did not work and it was driving me mad. Than I came across the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388429/uitableview-is-starting-with-an-offset-in-ios-7/23019724#23019724) suggesting the view hierarchy as the cause of some offset problems.

[image]

I was desperate so I tried moving this debug button from the top of the hierarchy like so:

[image]

weird jumping stopped.

Later I have learnt that your tableView should always be at the beginning of the view hierarchy so the autoadjustscrollinsets feature work properly and I have added:

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.tableView];

Just to be sure it always is because apple does not guarantee that it would not fiddle with .xibs hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to add the following code Settings to your UITableView

```
self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
```

Comment: Its about content offset not inset